# Prove $BCMD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral; two circles with common chord

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, solution-verification

Let $\overline{AB}$ be a common chord of two circles $k_1\;\&\;\;k_2$ and let straight line $p$ pass through $A$ s.t. $\;k_1\cap p\equiv C,k_2\cap p\equiv D$. Tangents through $C$ and $D$ of two circles, respectively, intersect each other at the point $M$. Prove $BCMD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

My attempt:

Let $S_1,S_2$ be centres of the circles respectively and $G\equiv k_1\cap CS_1,\; J\equiv k_2\cap DS_2$
$$AC\perp AG\;\&\;CM\perp CG\implies \measuredangle MCA=\measuredangle CGA=\measuredangle CBA$$
$$AD\perp AJ\;\&\; DM\perp DJ\implies\measuredangle ADM=\measuredangle AJD=\measuredangle ABD$$
$$\measuredangle CBD=\measuredangle CBA+\measuredangle ABD=\measuredangle MCA+\measuredangle ADM=180^{\circ}-\measuredangle DMC$$
So,$$\measuredangle CBD+\measuredangle DMC=\measuredangle MCB+\measuredangle BDM=180^{\circ}$$
$\implies\;BCMD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral
Picture:
[image]

Is this correct and are there any other interesting and efficient approaches?

Comment: nice drawing, what software did You use?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja, thank you! I'm too inert to keep pace with $IT$ development. First, I draw in GeoGebra, then I take a screenshot and cut it in Paint. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: sketch]

Mine look like this. If $\angle CAB=\theta$ then $\angle DAB=180-\theta$ and, $\angle S_{1}CB=90-\theta\rightarrow\angle MCB=180-\theta$
, $\angle S_{2}DB=90+\theta\rightarrow \angle MDB=\theta$.

$\angle MCB + \angle MDB = 180$ implies $MCBD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral

Comment: Interesting! How do you draw?

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya i drew on my iPad then snipped it :)