# Prove BMXN is cyclic.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons

Suppose $C_1$ and $C_2$ are circles such that {$,$}=$_{1}\cap _2$. We draw a secant $MN$ such that $\in _1$ and $\in _2$, and $A\in MN$. Show that if $X$ is the point of intersection of the tangents to $C_1$ and $C_2$ through $M$ and $N$ respectively, then the $$ quadrilateral is cyclic.

I have tried based on [this exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588981/prove-bcmd-is-a-cyclic-quadrilateral-two-circles-with-common-chord), but I cannot reach a conclusion, I would appreciate it very much if you could help me to solve it.

Comment: Are you sure this statement is right? If you draw a picture, do you find that this is true?

Comment: It is that drawing it left me an exercise similar to the one that I attached in the link. Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: Are you saying that the secant $MN$ is assumed to pass through $A$?

Comment: If the secant goes through A, the exercise is the same, right?

Comment: It's true in an example. I haven't thought about the proof yet.

Comment: But with A in the secant, the problem is the same as that of the link, right? if so it seems to me that this test works

Comment: Yes, it's the same. But you need to add this to your hypotheses. I haven't read the answer there, but if you're satisfied with it, then it's okay.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Because of tangent-chord property we have $\angle XMA = \angle MBA = x$ and $\angle XNA = \angle NBA = y$
- Since $\angle MXN = 180-x-y$ and $\angle MBN = x+y$ we have $\angle MXN+\angle MBN = 180$ which means $MXNB$ is cyclic.

[image]